# Change HTML-select element value with mousewheel in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, html-select

Is there any possibility to tell Firefox to use the mousewheel für scrolling through the select element. In firefox after selecting another value the select element looeses its focus, and in IE it doest loose its focus, so if i use my wheel the onchange event is fired.

Try [here](http://restive.bplaced.net/tests/selecttest.html).

Is there any solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tutorial on how to act on mousewheel events at http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-the-scroll-wheel.

Mootools is a good way of engaging this as well: see the tutorial at http://demos.mootools.net/CustomEvents

But, I'd recommend against using Javascript to change how a browser behaves. Firefox users (whether they're aware of it or not) learn to expect certain behaviors, so changing that would make your site harder to use. [Jakob Nielsens comment on 'the scroll wheel's revenge'](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/annoyances.html) comes immediately to mind.

Comment: many thanks for this detailed answer. I will think about your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

There is this really cool [jQuery Mouse Wheel Extension](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel)

> Adds mouse wheel support for your application! Just call mousewheel to add the event and call unmousewheel to remove the event.

[**Example**](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos)